# Checkbox processing with PHPexcel Output

Tags: php, checkbox, phpexcel, fpdf

This my script...

```
$students=isset ($_POST['students'])  ? $_POST['students'] : '';
for($i = 1; $i <= $students; $i++)
{
    $student = isset ($_POST['student'.$i]) ? $_POST['student'.$i]: '';

    $nilai= mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM student,s_semester where
    student.id=s_semester.student_id_fk AND student.id='$student' GROUP by student.id");

    $rowNya = 2;
    $no = 0;

    while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($nilai)) {
        $no = $no +1;


        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue("A$rowNya", $no)
            ->setCellValue("B$rowNya", $student)
            ->setCellValue("C$rowNya", $data['idcard'])
            ->setCellValue("D$rowNya", $data['status']);
        $rowNya = $rowNya + 1;
    }

    // Rename sheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
}

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="database_anggota.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

And my problem is, the excel output only one record of data that appears, i use checkbox before.. I check 3/4/5 or etc only 1 appears... If the output pdf and i use FPDF this script runnning well..

please help me...

Comment: If you execute that select statement in MySQLAdmin, how many rows does it return?

Comment: i use checkbox, nothing problem in query, if im not using PHPExcel this script running well. I want to display student score with multiplecheckbox and .xls as a output. I think problem was on " } " in for function. where should i put " } " for end of for function

Answer (score 1):

Move `$rowNya = 2;` to **before** the `for` loop, otherwise it's being reset for each student id... otherwise you're resetting it to 2 after each student, so it'll overwrite the previous student details

Comment: You right Mark, problem solved.. I put $rowNya before loop FOR... Thanks Mark